# Add data throw salesforce API without using user credentials

Tags: node.js, salesforce, crm, hubspot

I'm trying to give my users an option to add data to their Salesforce organization account without using their username and password from salesforce.

I'm already doing the same thing with Hubspot API through an API Key Hubspot provide.

From what I read so far, salesforce has two authentication options:

OAuth:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5

SOAP API Login:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm

I'm using NodeJS so I also checked JSForce library:
https://jsforce.github.io/

but again, **in all of them the user needs to provide his username and password.**
Does this option exist through the Salesforce API?

Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that all API access is done as a specific user and you must provide credentials to log in as such. See [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331470&type=1&mode=1).

You can use a scheduled apex job to make a callout to an external service from within your org at intervals using [one](http://amitsalesforce.blogspot.com/2017/08/webservice-callout-from-scheduled-apex.html) of several workarounds.